# Why am I getting scroll bars on element in some browsers?

Tags: html, css

I have a header element, containing a logo (floated left) and another div (floated right) and a hidden nav element. On the open_menu div on older PCs I am getting vertical scroll bars. As if one or two pixels are not fitting. It is as if the child div open_menu has a height greater than its parent the header and this is why the scroll bars appear. But this isn't the case, so why is this happening?

HTML and CSS:

```css
header {
  line-height: 71px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  overflow: auto;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
  width: 137px;
  height: 71px;
}

.open_menu {
  float: right;
  font-size: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

nav {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 72px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 102;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="index.html"><img src="resources/logo.svg" alt="xyz"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="open_menu" onclick="myFunction()">Menu</div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="work.html">Work</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Where is `myFunction()`?

Comment: myFunction( ) is some Javascript to make the nav appear when the open_menu is clicked

Comment: It would help if you actually included it, so we can see the problem.

Comment: I'm using a Mac. I noticed the problem on a PC. I don't have access to the PC so can't take a screen grab. However there are vertical scroll bars on the open_menu div. As if the open_menu div is not fitting by one or two pixels, hence the need for scroll bars.

Comment: How is anyone supposed to see what you're talking about if we just get an error when we click on the menu? Post a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. The problem is probably just that the browser's default style includes a border or margin that needs to be overridden, but it's hard to answer without seeing the problem.

Comment: I can't see the problem either. It only appears on older PC browsers. I'm going to checkout the potential answer below

Answer (score 0):

As explained in https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_clearfix.asp don't use `overflow: auto` for clearfix. Try the other way.

Comment: Yes but the height of the div is set by the line-height of the header. So I can't see why the open_menu div is not fitting inside the header

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to move the `line-height` from the `header` to the child `div` (open_menu). Hence the height of the header is determined by the child div.